# Using count in aggregation MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Using the aggregation below I'm trying to find the number of conversations solved by a Chatbot or Agent in office and out of office hours. With the aggregation below I'm getting a bunch of documents with the difference in solved and horario, which is 0 for out of office and 1 for in office conversations. My current result is the following:

[image: Result in conversations]

How can I get the following result, which adds up all the documents depending on the solved and the horario:

```
solved: Clipbot
horario: 0
count: 300
```

and

```
solved: Clipbot
horario: 1
count: 320
```

and

```
solved: Agent
horario: 0
count: 200
```

and

```
solved: Agent
horario: 1
count: 320
```

My current Aggregation:

```
[{$match: {
  start_date: {
    $gte: ISODate('2020-06-01 00:00:01'),
    $lte: ISODate('2020-06-30 23:59:59')
  }
}}, {$project: {
  solved: "$solved",
  hour: {
    $hour: {
      date: '$start_date',
      timezone: 'America/Mexico_City'
    }
  }
}}, {$project: {
  solved: "$solved",
  horario: {
    $cond: [
      {
        $and: [
        {
          $gt: [
            '$hour',
              7
          ]
          },
          {
            $lt: [
              '$hour',
                22
            ]
          },
        ]
      },
    1,
    0
    ]
  }
}}]
```

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#calculate-count-sum-and-average shows how to perform multiple accumulations.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `$group`, i have not added other fields that you have added in your query,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  // you can add your $match conditions here
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        solved: "$solved",
        horario: "$horario"
      },
      count: { $sum: 1 },
      solved: { $first: "$solved" },
      horario: { $first: "$horario" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: { _id: 0 }
  }
])
```

Working Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/gGWW7NXjaHy

Comment: @JorgeDeLaVegaCarrasco Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to [Accept your Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the questions you ask